# If $|f(z)|\le1$ if $|z|\le 1$ then $|a_k|\le1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the polynomial $f(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+ \dots+a_0$ is bounded by $1$ on a unit disc, which means $|f(z)|\le1$ if $|z|\le 1$. Prove that $|a_k|\le1$ for all  $k$.

I haven't found any idea for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $a_k= \frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)$ and use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: nice idea. If $C$ denotes the unit circle, then by cauchy's, i get

$$|a_k|\le\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{k+1}}$$

and then?

Comment: You should get $\displaystyle |a_k| \leq \sup\limits_{z \in C} \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{k+1}}$. But $|z|=1$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ if $z \in C$.

Comment: thank  for the explanation